# Are out there any PHP to Haxe translators?

Tags: php, wordpress, haxe

So I want to port WordPress to Haxe. I need HP to Haxe translators. Where can I get tham?

Comment: Do you have something against just wrapping WordPress as an external library? ala http://haxe.org/doc/php/extern_libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no php to haxe translators currently. You can try to write one but I suppose you will not be very successful, since PHP uses no types and resulting haxe code will be just a big bunch of Dynamics. Haxe also uses wrapers for many things(like arrays), so you will need to switch between haxe data and php data everywhere.
If you really want to do it the best way is just to port it by your hands(which is writing plenty of code lines though).

Answer (score 2):

You can look to [Php to Haxe translator from HaqTeam](http://phptohaxe.haqteam.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It could be awesome to have WordPress ported to Haxe but I highly doubt that a converter could do the job correctly; there are too many differences between PHP and Haxe:

- types will largely fail to be ported with the risk of having too many Dynamics even if not required
- no namespaces (at least in WordPress)
- the plugin logic should be completely reviewed

... and those are just from the top of my mind.

If you are serious about the porting I suggest making an accurate plan before starting ;)